# Greenfoot loop not working

Tags: greenfoot

This is my code

```
  import greenfoot.*;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class tableTester extends Actor
    {
    String userInput;
    int level;
    public void act() 
    {
        input();
        if(level == 1) {
            levelOne();
        } else {
            levelTwo();
        }
    }

public void input()
{
    do{
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 1 to play level 1 \nPress 2 to play level 2");
        Integer level = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }while((level <= 0) || (level >= 3));
}

public void levelOne()
{
    System.out.println("Level 1");
}

public void levelTwo()
{
        System.out.println("Level 2");
    }
}
```

I just started programming today and am trying to do a do while loop. i want it to loop until user enters either 1 or 2 and the next method is called (depending on the user input. if user enters one then method levelOne() is called, for 2 levelTwo() is called

Answer (score 0):

In input you are declaring a local "`level`" variable.  This level variable "shadows" the class "`level`" field.  So you are taking in the level variable, assigning it, then discarding it and exiting the method, where the code in your `act()` method has no effect because the level field is forever zero.  Best wau to fix the code is to avoid the variable declaration, by knocking off the `Integer` part:

```
public void input()
{
    do{
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Press 1 to play level 1 \nPress 2 to play level 2");
        level = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }while((level <= 0) || (level >= 3));
}
```

(Alternatively, you could return the value directly from the method, but that would take more code modifications.)